# html2canvas invokes error callback when trying to convert div to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app, html2canvas

I am designing a chrome web app that needs to convert a div with several children elements into a canvas, which will be used to generate a downloadable image.  I am currently using the [html2canvas library](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to try an achieve this functionality; however, rather than rendering a canvas element, the error callback is being invoked.  I have successfully used this library when creating simple local javascript web apps so I am convinced that something in the chrome developer specs is prohibiting this action.  Does anybody know how I can successfully execute my html2canvas code in my chrome application?  Is there another method/library that I can use in my chrome app to convert my div and its child elements into a canvas, which can later be transformed into an image? I will post what I have attempted below along with additional insight.

```
 //somebutton.onclick = function(){

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('div2canvas'),
    {
        // I have tried toggling these properties boolean values, no luck
        // allowTaint: true,
        // useCORS: true,

        onrendered: function(canvas){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            document.body.append(img);
        }
    }).then(
    // callback
    function(canvas) {
        // msg simply sends a message to the background page so that I can log data
        msg("I pass");
    },
    // error callback
    function(error){
        // the error is always logged
        msg("i fail");
    });
    // this message is always printed
    msg("button: end");
//}
```

Let me know if posting more code will help, this is a rather large project so I will try to post the appropriate code snippets.

Comment: What's the error message

Comment: The error parameter logs an empty object, I'm not sure if there is a message associated with it.

Comment: I see several similar issues, try googling for "chrome app canvas.toDataURL error".